# Declaring type interface for object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't figure out what's wrong with this type declaration given the interface.

[image]

TS is saying: `State is an unresolved variable`.

Anybody know why that is syntactically incorrect? (According to Webstorm and the tsc compiler.)

Comment: It'd be easier to answer if you included the code in the screenshot as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `state` is a property of the [`React.Component` class](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/index.d.ts#L165-L184) and you have declared it as `any` via the second [type variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
class Home extends React.Component<any, any> {
                                     // ^
                                     // This type variable declares the type for state
```

Instead, you should delcare it like this:

```
class Home extends React.Component<any, State> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { items: [] };
    }
}
```

Note that the `React.Component`'s `props` will be `any` (via the first type variable), which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: thanks, do you happen to know what the first parameter is for, if the second one is for this.state? Is it for this.props?

Comment: Yep, it's for the props. The answer has a link to the relevant TypeScript declaration, if you are interested.

Comment: ahh nice, thanks, I was wondering what those type params were for!

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the variable **state**. I think compiler is considering **State** as variable instead of type.

```
interface State {
    items: Array<string>[];
}

export class Home {

    private state: State;
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = { items: [] }
    }
}
```

*Also you should provide a type for Array object in your interface, as shown in example above.*